# Finger counting method

Tags: combinatorics

5here are 10 fingers( 5 on each hands),

> # of ways to hold up exactly 3 fingers?
>    # of ways to hold up exactly 3 fingers on each hand?
>    # of ways to hold some finger up, when i'm holding up at least one in each hand?

I believe the answer for the first is $\binom{10}3$ and for second one it would
be $\binom{5}3+\binom{5}3$. Am I right on this part?

I believe the 3rd one holds same logic. Can someone explain this with
thorough explanation?

Comment: I think the second one is $\binom53*\binom53$

Answer (score 3):

For the third, the complementary situation is that one hand or the other has no fingers up. There are $1\cdot2^5+2^5\cdot1-1\cdot1$ ways to do that. Subtract this from $2^{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your first + sec answers are right.

Third case, thinking about choosing only 1 finger from 10 fingers, how many cases are there?

Comment: The second is not right; see Stefan's comment. And it sounds like you are misunderstanding the question in the third part.